# Infowindow only opens on one pin on Google Map with multiple pins

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I searched for similar questions but found none, apologies if I missed one.

I'm trying to learn functionality for creating an infowindow that appears on the most recently clicked pin, and pulls through relevant information.

The problem is that whichever pin I click, the infowindow always appears on the same one pin ('Cool event 5' in the code below).

```
var locations = [
  ['Cool event 1', 33.890542, 151.274856, 'address 1'],
  ['Cool event 2', 33.923036, 151.259052, 'address 2'],
  ['Cool event 3', 34.028249, 151.157507, 'address 3'],
  ['Cool event 4', 33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 'address 4'],
  ['Cool event 5', 33.950198, 151.259302, 'address 5']
];
```

I'm guessing it's a problem with the marker code:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlngset,
  map: map,
  title: event
  });
```

Full code can be found in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jotpd9ff/5/)

Ta!

**EDIT: I'd uploaded the wrong version of the jsfiddle, this is now fixed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:  like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/7yceq7jq/

---

Inside the onClick function you must specify which marker was clicked on (by the client).

Here is one way:

```
<script>
var markers = [];  // put this global, or at least make sure the variable is accessible to the rest of your code
...
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
...
});
// now push this marker on the array
markers.push(marker);
... 
marker.addListener('click', function(e) {
  var index = markers.indexOf(this);  // if index = 0 => first marker; ...
  // set content
  infowindow.setContent = locations[index][0] ; // this adds the name of the location, feel free to add more stuff 
  infowindow.open(map, markers[index]);
})
</script>
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Cheers Emmanuel. I made the changes you suggested but I'm still having the same issue: [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jotpd9ff/4/)

It's very likely I implemented them incorrectly as I'm new to JS - will keep tinkering